# Add space between elements using sanitize and truncate in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

Working on HTML content and trying to generate some excerpt for every post, I'm using the following code to sanitize and then truncate, but the issue is that the generated text without any spaces.

```
= sanitize(post.body, tags: []).truncate(155, separator: ' ...').html_safe
```

The following image form the editor, every word is a single `p`
 element, there may be any HTML element like images, video, .. . I only want to show only text.

[image]

The following image is the view, I want to add spaces between theses words (`p` elements)

[image]

Inspector

[image]

How I can sanitize, truncate the content and keeping the format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you dont have spaces around the tags i.e 
The text is something like

```
include ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper

> content = "<p>this</p><p>is</p><p>great</p><p>and</p><p>for</p><p>some</p><p>reason</p>"
> strip_tags(content)
> "thisisgreatandforsomereason"

> content = "<p>this </p><p>is </p><p>great </p><p>and </p><p>for </p><p>some </p><p>reason </p>"
> strip_tags(content)
> "this is great and for some reason"
```

either try giving spaces around the `<p>` tag or use regex to create spaces

for ex

```
> content = "<p>this</p><p>is</p><p>great</p><p>and</p><p>for</p><p>some</p><p>reason</p>"
> strip_tags(content.gsub('</p>', ' </p>')) # Note the space in replaced content
> "this is great and for some reason"
```

Comment: Exactly! Using the regex fixed the problem. Thanks so much Deepak